# How to resize interactively layer in jCanvas

Tags: jcanvas

I would like to make anchor points (handlers like in FabricJS) for change the size, width and height of any element drawn on layers with jCanvas. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Previously, there was no easy way to create a resizable shape in jCanvas. However, I have recently released a jCanvas plugin, called Handles, that will allow you to do just that. You can [download and read the documentation for Handles on its plugin page](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/plugins/handles/).